Angular Build Fails: "Maximum call stack size exceeded"
I’m working on an Angular project and encountered multiple issues when trying to run the application using ng serve. The build fails with the following errors:
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Error: Can't resolve './node_modules/angular-archwizard/styles/archwizard.css' in '/home/seifou/projects/monitor-dz/monitorDZ-FRONT'

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Checked for circular dependencies in my AppModule and other modules
but didn’t find any obvious issues.
Cleared node_modules and reinstalled dependencies using npm install.
Updated my angular.json to ensure all styles are properly included.

Relevant details:

Angular version: 16.2.0
Node version: 18.19.1

package.json
{
  "name": "vien-angular",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.20.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --output-path Vien-angular --aot --configuration production"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^3.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^36.0.1",
    "@glidejs/glide": "^3.4.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^11.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@perfectmemory/ngx-contextmenu": "^16.0.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.1.0",
    "angular-archwizard": "^6.1.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.22",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^11.0.0",
    "angular2-hotkeys": "^13.4.0",
    "angular2-notifications": "^16.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "ckeditor4-angular": "^5.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "express": "^4.18.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "firebase": "^11.0.2",
    "html-to-pdfmake": "^2.1.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.3.2",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^11.0.2",
    "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^16.0.0",
    "ngx-ellipsis": "^4.1.3",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^23.0.0",
    "nouislider": "^15.8.1",
    "openai": "^4.4.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.15",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "sortablejs": "^1.15.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "video.js": "^8.19.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.81.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.4.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}

angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Vien-Angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["src/assets/css/sass"]
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.rtl.only.min.css",
              "./node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.core.min.css",
              "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css",
              "./node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/angular-archwizard/archwizard.css",
              "./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-lightbox/lightbox.css",
              "./node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.blueyale.scss",
              "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.bluenavy.scss",
              "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.blueolympic.scss",
              "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.blueyale.scss",
              "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.bluenavy.scss",
              "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.blueolympic.scss",
              "./node_modules/nouislider/dist/nouislider.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": {
              "scripts": true,
              "styles": true,
              "vendor": false
            },
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true,
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "firebase",
              "@firebase/app",
              "@firebase/database",
              "@firebase/firestore",
              "@firebase/functions",
              "@firebase/performance",
              "@firebase/remote-config",
              "@firebase/component",
              "@videojs/xhr",
              "global/document",
              "global/window",
              "keycode",
              "mux.js/lib/tools/parse-sidx",
              "mux.js/lib/utils/clock",
              "safe-json-parse/tuple",
              "videojs-vtt.js",
              "ngx-quill",
              "ngx-lightbox",
              "chart.js",
              "pdfmake/build/pdfmake",
              "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts",
              "file-saver",
              "moment"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Vien-Angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Vien-Angular:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Vien-Angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Vien-Angular:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Vien-Angular:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}

Any guidance on resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated!

This might happens also due to RAM of your machine.
Other people has already asked the same question.
A similar question
Anyway you re not giving more information.
Does it happens directly on the ng serve, on reload, did you added any module, did you made any change and before wasnt happening ?
You can try to check the stack call by hitting the Performance tab on Chrome debugger tools for further analyse.

thanks for you response, in fact yeah I want to upgrade from 14 to 15 and 16
I will edit the question to add angular.json and package.json

Can you update also when its happening and RAM of your PC

I have 32 Go RAM so I don't think so that it's because of the RAM

Can you check carefully if you have mistakenly imported this monitorDZ-FRONT.The error is coming from archwizard.cs. Can you comment for a while and retry ?

I did it, comment all what about archwizard,
but I still have the same issue
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Can you create minimal stackblitz code or push the current one ?

Hello Stefani, if you have time we can do a little call to see what I did ... tell me which platform you prefer .. google meet  the faster one

Put the code here and share it please: https://stackblitz.com/
